# Change html element class that is under another element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the class of an html element **i** using jquery. What i'm trying to achieve is when the user clicks on **div** , I would like the CSS class of the **i** under the clicked **div** to change.

So far I'm unable to achieve this. Any tip will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.gen').click(function() {
    $(this).next('span i').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-up fa-angle-double-down');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<li>
  <div class="gen"><span>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>John</figcaption>
         </div>

         <i class=" stack-top box arrow bounce fa fa-angle-double-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>Jane</figcaption>
         </div>
       </span>
  </div>
</li>
<hr>
<li>
  <div class="gen"><span>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>John2</figcaption>
         </div>

         <i class=" stack-top box arrow bounce fa fa-angle-double-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>Jane2</figcaption>
         </div>
       </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), as following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.gen').click(function() {
     $(this).find('span i').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-up fa-angle-double-down');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<li>
  <div class="gen"><span>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>John</figcaption>
         </div>

         <i class=" stack-top box arrow bounce fa fa-angle-double-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>Jane</figcaption>
         </div>
       </span>
  </div>
</li>
<hr>
<li>
  <div class="gen"><span>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>John2</figcaption>
         </div>

         <i class=" stack-top box arrow bounce fa fa-angle-double-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
         <div class="inline-block"> 
           <figcaption>Jane2</figcaption>
         </div>
       </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

The find method should do the trick instead of next since find traverses down the DOM

```
 $(this).find('span i').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-up fa-angle-double-down');
```